# In spoken Mandarin, what adjectives can be used to complement a person's appearance?

Tags: mandarin, vocabulary

In spoken Mandarin Chinese what adjectives can be used to complement a person's appearance?

I can think of a couple off the top of my head:

- 美丽 - Měilì - Beautiful
- 可爱 - Kě'ài - Cute
- 性感 - Xìnggǎn - Sexy

I've been looking around but having trouble finding any information relating to this subject

Assuming a pre-existing close relationship with the person you're complimenting, what compliments would be used in a informal setting?

---

Question updated to be more concise, also declaring "pre-existing close relationship" as someone you have known for a period greater then 6 months whom you're comfortable speaking freely around

Comment: Surely there are countless ways to compliment someone on their appearance! Can you narrow down the question a bit?

Comment: @congusbongus I was scared it might be too broad, however not being a native speaker it's hard to know the scope of a question and if I said "commonly used" that would quickly become opinion based. I've narrowed it down probably as far as I can with my current knowledge of the language but if you feel it would be to broad fell free to flag the question

Comment: @50-3 It would be good if you can scope down on these factors: casual or formal, spoken or written, descriptive or appraising, and gender and age of the person to be applied.

Comment: @NS.X. Question updated, as for Spoken or Written would the mandarin Tag not be enough to imply it's spoken or does it need to be declared in the body

Comment: @50-3 No it's not enough, spoken and written Mandarin can be very different in many cases. Also you may want to clarify whether you are in or desire a romantic relationship with that lady or you're just normal friends; Would you like the word/phrase to sound objective or convey strong personal emotion; etc.

Comment: There are countless ways to compliment a person. Please narrow down the scope to a specific compliment that you are interested in.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow are you indicating that unless I'm asking for a translation of a phrase my question is too broad?

Comment: No, what makes you think so?

Comment: "Please narrow down the scope to a specific compliment that you are interested in" would make me think you're suggesting I need to narrow it down to a single compliment

Comment: There are many ways to praise a person for being pretty alone. E.g, 漂亮,秀丽,俏丽,美丽 and each having a slightly different meaning. And to compliment someone for being sexy, you can have another long list of phrases and idioms. Your question is simply too broad. This is what I am saying.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow I'm unlikely to be able to narrow it down any more as I wasn't looking for something very precise at this stage, so feel free to flag it for a mod to make a decision on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer to a narrower version of the question, by only looking at single characters associated with good appearance. Hopefully this can help you understand what the multi-character versions mean.

Note that characters with a female radical tend to be used for females only.

Also, note that these single characters often change meaning when used in different contexts, so do not use this as a guide to mix-and-match and make your own words!

> 美: beautiful
>
> 丽: beautiful
>
> 秀: elegant
>
> 俊: handsome
>
> 俏: spruce
>
> 媚: charming
>
> 娇: tender
>
> 娆: graceful
>
> 艳: gorgeous
>
> 雅: refined
>
> 致: delicate
>
> 华: splendid

Comment: I feel like example words are important (you can't mix and match _all_ of these at random).

Comment: I've been told that 美 cannot properly be used to describe a person's beauty.  漂亮 is the better choice, unless you are reciting, or composing poetry and you are making a metaphor.

Answer (score 4):

Some other words are:

> 漂亮 (piàoliang)
>   秀丽 (xiùlì)
>   姣好 (jiāohǎo)
>   俏丽 (qiàolì)
>   标致 (biāozhì)
>   文雅 (wényǎ)

The adjectives you came about and the words above often used for females. By the way it's sometimes impolite to describe a girl as 性感。

Comment: To what extent is 性感 impolite? Is it purely based upon your relationship with the other party or are there times it should not be said to say your partner

Comment: This words was invented under the influence of western countries. The traditional Chinese didn't use this word. So, if a girl is very traditional, she may don't like you to say this to her. You'd better not to say this to strangers.

Comment: Can you add translations for `姣好` and `俏丽`? (I can't find these in online dictionaries)

Comment: @Cocowalla Trying to find these myself so far in my research I can tell you `姣` means cunning/pretty other usage `姣俏` pretty/handsome `姣童` Handsome boy. `俏` pretty/smart/handsome `俏丽` Beautiful or good looking.

Comment: @50-3 Indeed true for 性感. Just traditional culture issues. Careful!